# Как убрать информацию в таких <> скобках при выводе в Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вывод, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Нужно, чтобы при запуске ячеек отображалось только то, что является результатом выполнения кода. То есть требуется не отображать сгенерированные колабом сообщения по типу: `<Axes: >` перед графиком.
Пример кода:

```py
    import seaborn as sns
    # data - датасет в формате pandas.DataFrame
    colours = ['LemonChiffon', '#cc1b00'] 
    sns.heatmap(data.isnull(), cmap=sns.color_palette(colours))
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста примеры кода и результаты его вывода

Comment: добавила. Нужно убрать `<Axes: >`

Answer (score 0):

Функция `sns.heatmap()` возвращает объект `AxesSubplot` из библиотеки `Matplotlib`. В Google Colab при выводе этот объект отображается как `<Axes: >`. В итоге есть несколько решений. Правильным на мой взгляд являеться стандартный вызов графика командой `plt.show()` (Не забываем импортировать `matplotlib` хоть в Google Colab это и не обязательно):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
colours = ['LemonChiffon', '#cc1b00']

sns.heatmap(data.isnull(), cmap=sns.color_palette(colours))
plt.show()
```

Вторым решением, которое я нашёл, это простое создание переменной и сохранения в ней результатов:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data.isnull(), cmap=sns.color_palette(colours))
```